# Add hyperlink style to Telerik Report

Tags: asp.net, css, xslt, telerik, telerik-reporting

Question:
    I need to add the internal style below to a Telerik Report. Please note a0 and a1 are classes.
    The style sheet is given below: How do I convert this into an XML style sheet that a telerik report accepts.
     Refer to : http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/style-understanding-style-selectors.html
    But the link does not give you detail on how to add a hyperlink selector into an XML style sheet.

CSS below:

```
a.a0:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
}
a.a1:link {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Below is how I worked around the above issue:
ReportViewer.prototype.OnReportLoadedOld = ReportViewer.OnReportLoaded;
                ReportViewer.prototype.OnReportLoaded = function() {
                    this.OnReportLoadedOld();

var reportFrame = document.getElementById(this.reportFrameID);
                    var reportDocument = reportFrame.contentWindow.document;
                    var body = reportDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

 $(".a1", body).css("text-decoration", "underline");
 $(".a0", body).css("text-decoration", "underline");

You can achive the hover like this:

$(".a1", body).hover(function() {
        $(".a1", body).css("text-decoration", "underline");
      }, function () {
       $(".a1", body).css("text-decoration", "underline");
  });
```